# Writing test cases for private classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, jvm, junit4, java-11

There is a public class in which a private class has been written with some properties and methods. Now, we want to write test cases for this private class but since it's a private class, we can't create an instance of that class. I tried using reflection utils, but that can help only for private methods of public classes.

```java
public class Class1{
    private class Class2{
        int a1;
        void method () { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some unit test frameworks might be able to do this.  However I usually avoid making things private that I need to test, so I'm not really sure which ones to use specifically in this case.  Look around!

Comment: If  it is just a test ,you can  modify ```Class2```  be a inner static class temporary ,so that you can instantiate class2 and test your method. In general , wo often use some test framework like junit , here is [doc](https://junit.org/junit5/)

Comment: You shouldn't test private methods or classes directly; test them through observable behaviour of package private (or higher) classes and methods.

Comment: There must be some code in `Class1` that calls that method in `Class2`.  That's the code that you should be testing.

Comment: Yes, there's a code in Class1 which calls methods of Class2, but somehow that couldn't be tested.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection, I was able to get the following to work.

Consider the following, `Class1`, and `Class2`.

```java
public class Class1 {
    private class Class2 {
        int a1;
        void method() {
            System.out.println("value");
        }
    }
}
```

The following method will return an instance of `Class2`.

```java
Class1.Class2 instance() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Class<?> object = Class1.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
    Constructor<?> constructor = object.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    return (Class1.Class2) constructor.newInstance(class1);
}
```

Additionally, from the JUnit4 Frequently Asked Questions.

[JUnit4 - How do I test private methods?](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#atests_11)

> Testing private methods may be an indication that those methods should be moved into another class to promote reusability.
>
> But if you must...
>
> If you are using JDK 1.3 or higher, you can use reflection to subvert the access control mechanism with the aid of the [PrivilegedAccessor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/privaccessor/). For details on how to use it, read [this article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/12/reflection.html).
>
> If you are using JDK 1.6 or higher and you annotate your tests with @Test, you can use Dp4j to inject reflection in your test methods. For details on how to use it, see [this test script](http://dp4j.com/testscript).

Comment: 'should be moved into another class to promote reusability.' is some weird verbiage. The essence of it is: "If you want to test a private method, then that's a very strong indication that method should not be private". Same applies to private classes, of course. OP: You can have package private, too. Test code has no issues accessing those.

Comment: Here, the issue is for private classes, not private methods. Of course, there should be rarely some private class within another class, but since it is there, we can't change it for now, and think of a way to solve the issue

Comment: @GlidingSwords997 I think that's what the documentation is inferring.  If you have a situation where this is occurring, then it's more logical to re-evaluate the structure.

Comment: @GlidingSwords997, I've provided an abstraction using reflection, if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If the access modifier of the embedded class were combined with a public getter, then it'd be more feasible and reliable. Also, it would force you to have a new instance every time `retrieveClass()` is called.

Say...

```
public class Class1 { 
  private class Class2 { 
   int a1; 
   void method ();
  }
   public Class2 retrieveClass() { 
     return new Class2();
 }  
}
```

Even if you had reflection handle it behind the scenes with a sort of mocking type of behavior, It may work but also I would not rely on that wonky code. Since you need it testable.

Alternatively, these may be the undesired workarounds to go by:

```
   Method method = TargetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argClasses);
   method.setAccessible(true);
   return method.invoke(targetObject, argObjects);


   Class obj = test.getClass(); // create an object of the class named Class

   Field field = obj.getDeclaredField("fieldname"); // access the private variable

   field.setAccessible(true); // make private field accessible

   field.set(test,"value"); // setting a field value
```

Comment: Since its a code written by someone else, we can't change the source code. Had it been protected or static, there would be no issue

Comment: you could go the messy way of hacking it out to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

UnitTest do not *test code*, they verify the *pubic observable behavior* of the code under test. That is *return values* and *communication with dependencies* according to the parameters passed in.

Your private class is an *implementation detail*, your current decision how your unit realizes its *desired behavior*. You may later change your mind and omit this class in favor of some different approach resulting in the same behavior. This is known as refactoring. In that case all your unittests "testing" this class would become useless and the safety net, that unittests  build for detecting unwanted changes in the units behaviors, will get a big hole. When doing unittests correctly you can change *implementation details* without changing the unittest and the latter will guarantee that the units behavior did not change unexpectedly.

In Consequence you should **not** test the private class *explicitly*. That means you should create testcases against the public class, that use this private class *implicitly*.